# conversion php multidimensional associative array to json

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional associative array from a mysql table as follows:

```
$i = 0;
$data = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
$arr = array();
$arr['id'] = $i;
$arr['code'] = $row['code'];
$arr['name'] = $row['name'];
$data[$i] = $arr;
$i++;
}
```

I would convert those array to json by this script

```
var data  = <?php echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) ?>;
```

but there is'n no response, so i tried with this script

```
var data  = <?php echo json_encode($data) ?>;
```

both of those script do not give the correct result

so I tried the other ways with the following script in order to generate a string variable that will further my convert it to json

```
$i = 0;
$data = '[';
while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
if ($data != "[") {$data .= ",";}
$data .= '{"id":"'  . $i . '",';
$data .= '"code":"' . $row["code"] . '",';
$data .= '"name":"' . $row["name"] . '"}'; 
$i++;
}
$data .="]";
```

Then i change to json with these script:

```
var data = <?php echo $data ?>;
```

the result is still wrong

is there any improvement suggestions for me, thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the bad JSON being spat out. Thanks for improving the question's reference value and making it more answerable!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try providing a header before you return your json array. Just before encoding your json add the part `header('Content-Type: application/json');` This way you can pass $data as JSON to the browser

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array('success' => TRUE, 'data' => $data));
```